# How to improve attach bulk Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I try to attach rating to the user using many to many relation:

```
foreach ($rating as $value) {
    $rateduser->rates()->attach($value->rateid, ['order_id' => $order->getId(), 'user_id' => $user->getId(), 'rate' => $value->rate]);
}
```

As you can see I try to attach rate, rateid and additional data one by one. So it is exeecuted over 5 queries at time.

Is it possible to use one bulk insert request?

Comment: The documentation for `attach()` shows that you can attach multiple at once: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#attaching-detaching (scroll down a bit). Something like `->attach([1 => [...], 2 => [...]])`. You can construct an array while iterating `foreach($rating as $value)` (or a function like `map()`), then after the loop, call `$rateduser->rates()->attach($arrayFromLoop)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

attach accept an array for mass attaching where the index is the foreign key

```
$toBeAttached = [];
foreach ($rating as $value) {
    $toBeAttached[$value->rateid] = ['order_id' => $order->getId(), 'user_id' => $user->getId(), 'rate' => $value->rate];
}
if ($toBeAttached) {
    $rateduser->rates()->attach($toBeAttached);
}
```

Attach doesnt check for existing values, it can create duplicate entries.
Another solution would be to use `sync()` which will detach everything then attach the provider ones.

```
if ($toBeAttached) {
    $rateduser->rates()->sync($toBeAttached);
}
```

The better solution to avoid duplicates is to use `syncWithoutDetaching()` but it consumes more performance

```
if ($toBeAttached) {
    $rateduser->rates()->syncWithoutDetaching($toBeAttached);
}
```

For more details, here the documentation related to [syncing-associations](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations)

Comment: What id the values already exist, could I update it using attach?

Comment: Would you update attach change to sync

Comment: @RamilHuseynov adeed needed explanations and examples